# Using zref in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, zref

I am writing a package for lecture's slides and script that should be used by third persons at our department.

I want to use features of the zref package together with beamer, but in a transparent way, i.e. the user should be able to continue to use the `\label` command.
While it is sufficient in the `<article>` mode to have `let\label=\zref@label` to get `\zref@newlabel` instead of `\newlabel` in the aux file, this has not effect in the `<presentation>` mode. Redefining `\beamer@origlabel` does not work either.

Consider the following example:

```
% \documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[counter,user]{zref}
\makeatletter
\let\label=\zref@label
\makeatother

\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{foo}
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}
  \label{mylabel}
  mycounter is \themycounter
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Then, one can find in the aux file:

```
\zref@newlabel{mylabel}{\default{1}\page{1}\counter{mycounter}}
```

If I comment in the first line but comment out the following both lines, I get only (a.o):

```
\newlabel{mylabel}{{1}{1}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

What is the best way to enable zref there?

Comment: Providing a MWE would deliver this question much more transparent ;-)

Comment: And maybe you could describe why you want to use zref.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some `counter` and `\label` - related commands are redefined by packages and/or their action is shifted to the `\@begindocumenthook` command (`\AtBeginDocument`) - this must be done for `\let\label\zref@label` too, otherwise its definition is overruled by other settings.

I've not tested whether this other `\label` command would have consequences and I don't know how it would cooperate with `cleveref` as well.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[counter,user]{zref}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\label=\zref@label
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{foo}
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}
  \label{mylabel}
  mycounter is \themycounter
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```